# Cout doesn't display all fields (C++, MySQL)

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a function:

```
int main()
{
    MySQL::Connect("127.0.0.1", 3306, "root", "", "player");
    MySQL::ExecuteQuery("select * from player");

    while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
    {
        std::cout << row[2] << "\n";

        MySQL::SetDatabase("account");
        MySQL::ExecuteQuery("select * from account"); // This function causes a problem.

        // while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            // break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which should get everything of player names from `player` table what it does and what it display in console (I'm posting a screenshot of table in Navicat):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6HJQ.png

However, when `MySQL::ExecuteQuery("select * from account");` function is used which selects everything in account table, the earlier `std::cout` display only one player name instead of two:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ZkP.png

What can I do in this situation? Or is there another simple way to connect to MySQL in C++? Please help.

I attach files such as MySQL_Func.cpp and MySQL_Func.h which include problematic function:

```
.cpp:
```

```
#include "MySQL_Func.h"
#include "../Log.hpp"

MYSQL* conn;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES* res;

std::string conf_ip;
unsigned int conf_port;
std::string conf_db;
std::string conf_login;
std::string conf_password;

std::string error = mysql_error(conn);
int err = 0;

namespace MySQL
{
    void Connect(std::string ip, unsigned int port, std::string login, std::string password, std::string db)
    {
        conf_ip = ip;
        conf_port = port;
        conf_login = login;
        conf_password = password;
        conf_db = db;

        if (conn != 0)
        {
            SendLog(0, "MySQL has been restared.");
            mysql_close(conn);
        }

        conn = mysql_init(0);

        if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, ip.c_str(), login.c_str(), password.c_str(), db.c_str(), port, NULL, 0))
        {
            error = mysql_error(conn);
            SendLog(1, "Connection with database was failed: " + error + ".");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            SendLog(0, "Successfully connected with database!");
        }
    }

    void ExecuteQuery(std::string query)
    {
        err = mysql_query(conn, query.c_str());
        res = mysql_store_result(conn);

        if (res != 0) // Protection against NullPointer.
        {
            int total_rows = mysql_num_fields(res);
            if (total_rows != 0) // If total rows isn't 0.
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    error = mysql_error(conn);
                    SendLog(1, "Query execute failed:" + error + ".");
                    mysql_free_result(res);
                    exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    SendLog(0, "Query has been sent (" + query + ")!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SendLog(1, "Query has been sent: (" + query + ") but its value is 0.");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    void SetDatabase(std::string current_db)
    {
        if (current_db != conf_db) // If current_db isn't conf_db.
            MySQL::Connect(conf_ip, conf_port, conf_login, conf_password, current_db);
    }
}
```

```
.h:
```

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>

extern MYSQL* conn;
extern MYSQL_ROW row;
extern MYSQL_RES* res;

extern std::string conf_ip;
extern unsigned int conf_port;
extern std::string conf_db;
extern std::string conf_login;
extern std::string conf_password;

namespace MySQL
{
    void Connect(std::string ip, unsigned int port, std::string login, std::string password, std::string db);
    void ExecuteQuery(std::string query);
    void SetDatabase(std::string database);
}
```

Comment: ExecuteQuery inside the loop overrides res used in the loop condition.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `MySQL::ExecuteQuery` return a `MYSQL_RES*` instead of using global state?

Comment: Thanks everyone for helpful answers, problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two calls to ExecuteQuery share state, namely the "currently active query" and the buffered resultset you downloaded with `mysql_result_row`.
This is called a *non-reentrant* function.

Some options:

- have a dedicated connection for each query
- Do a single query that somehow combines the results (ie JOIN the `players` and `accounts` table)
- Fetch all the players first into a dedicated datastructure (eg `std::vector` or `std::map`), then do the query for accounts later.